# No images showing up in email activity D365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We have a problem that in the email activity when multiple inline images are included, the images completely stop loading. Emails with a few images are displayed without problems, but if there are a lot of images, they do not appear in the attachment.

[image]

In addition to the missing images, I get a large number of error messages in the console for this email activity only. Here are some screenshots of the error messages.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the network trace log for reference:
[image]

[image]

Our system specifications:

- Dynamics 365 Online - Customer Service.
- DB version: 9.2
- Region: Europe

Comment: This may cause by some plugin timeout. Email Image stores in Azure Blob and should has a plugin on retrieve/retrievemultiple to get the body to show up, this need time to be done. You may check the plugin trace, there should be some retrievemultiple and retrieve plugin trace log.

Comment: Only the last 2 days are visible in the plugin trace logs. The email activity was created 5 days ago, so I can't check that. When I refresh the email I don't see any retrievemultiple plugin trace log.

Comment: Any timeout request in the browser network trace?

Comment: No, nothing of that sort is showing up

Comment: The last error in your screenshot says "timed out after 10000ms"?

Comment: yeah, but it's enclosed as a message, so it's not directly the browser I'm running. I believe it's a timed out error from the service which was trying to execute. I will post the whole timed out error message.

Comment: hmm, I can't display the full error message anymore. previously I saw that the service which should be executed was PCFGridControl

Comment: can you switch to Network tab and share the screenshot? You should find out some red rows.

Comment: I added the network trace log. I can't see any red rows, but the errors above still appear

Comment: most probably you already looked into [this question](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/390456/received-email-inline-images-not-showing-up) but if not give it a try and let me know if it helps

Comment: yeah, I have seen that. already tried the solution but it did not work for me. this post is really the last hope for this problem :D

Comment: Can you find any network requests with **activitymimeattachments** in URL?

Comment: yeah, I found 2 requests and both have Status 200. I added them above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for missing inline images:**
We changed the default font and size which is only possible by adding a custom
"EmailRTEconfig.js". That is currently the only way to change settings of the email editor. The documentation says you only need to add the changes to the js file but that's incorrect. We had to add all settings and changed what we needed. By doing so the issue was resolved. Maybe the custom "rte config" file is not put on top but overwrites the default file completely.

**Solution for missing attachments in the list:**
The problem got solved by adding this flag to the end of the email activity url: "&flags=DisableFormHandlers=true". It disables the scripts (onyl for that load) which would trigger by loading the form. This flag does not disable the scripts, only for that one reload. By adding the flag you can check if the problem is triggered by any of your custom scripts. In my case the issue was coming from a custom script. All I had to do was deactivating the custom scripts, make a hard refresh and then activate them again. After that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that there is a new and editable `EmailRTEconfig.js`:

```
EmailRTEconfig_editable.js
```

Display name: `msdyn_EmailRTEconfig_referenceonly.js`

However, if I add this to the as a RTE Control in the Email Description column, the inline images are not shown either in received emails or (Outlook) sent emails.